# Remove application from Typesafe Activator

Tags: typesafe-activator

I recreated the same project multiple times, previously deleting it from disk.

Now the 'Open existing app...' is populated with inexistent projects and Typesafe Activator is adding an incremental suffix to them *project-name-1, project-name-2, project-name-n*.

How do I remove or delete an application from 'Open existing app...' list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not implemented yet.  However, you can look under `~/.activator/<version>/config.json` and directly remove the application there. If you want to remove all the applications either delete the file or set to `{"applications":[]}`  We haven't documented the config.json format, because we haven't locked on a stable config file there yet, hence why it's under a versioned directory.

I believe there's already a ticket for the feature: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/17

Comment: Can´t find config.json. My version is 1.3.5, has it changed?

Comment: The config file now seems to be in `~/.activator/1.0/config.json`

Comment: I can confirm that the other answer is right: It's implemented now.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of activator has a delete button!
[image: delete button is a cross in a grey circle. it can be found on the right hand side of the application listing in the right hand "open existing app" sidebar]